# How to mock DOM in Typescript unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, dom, mocha.js, chai, typescript2.0

I am writing some unit tests in TypeScript 2.4.2 for a library written in the same language.
Some test case require access to properties such `document.location.href`, so I need to mock the DOM.
The test runner is Mocha and the assertion framework is Chai.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: **Doesnt work** isnt a working problem description for us. Consider putting up that [mcve] and clearly describing in which way "it doesnt work" and fails your expectations.

Comment: @GhostCat I just edit my question. My problem is not about a specific code but more "how to do that".

Answer (score 3):

Well, after many hours of headache and this post on SO, I finally find a way to do it:

1. Install the [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global) and [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) module: `npm install --save-dev jsdom  jsdom-global`
2. Create a file named `dom-mock.js`, for example.
3. In this file, add this:

```html
require('jsdom-global')(/* any html you need */, {
    /* any jsdom options you need, e.g: */
    url: "https://example.org/",
    referrer: "https://example.com/"
});
```

4. Run the tests by registering the dom mock you just created: `mocha -r tests/mocks/dom-mock.js -r ts-node/register tests/*.ts`

If you do not need DOM customization, just run `mocha -r jsdom-global/register -r ts-node/register tests/*.ts`